# Retrieve coordinates relative to a window through a local hook

Tags: c++, dll, coordinates, hook, mouse

I'm trying to retrieve the coordinates relative to a window through a local mouse hook (WH_MOUSE). According to MSDN, the MouseProc's `lParam` is equivalent to the `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT` struct, which contains a `POINT` value that is relative to the *screen*. I tried calling `ScreenToClient` to convert the coordinates to be relative to the window, but it returns invalid values.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code >= 0)
    {
        MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* mouse = reinterpret_cast<MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        POINT point = mouse->pt;

        ScreenToClient(mouse->hwnd, &point);

        // x = point.x;
        // y = point.y;

        // x = mouse->pt.x;
        // y = mouse->pt.y;
        
        // x = LOWORD(mouse->wHitTestCode);
        // y = HIWORD(mouse->wHitTestCode);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Shouldn't the `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT::pt` value be relative to `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT::hwnd`? How do I get the mouse coordinates relative to a window (preferable through local hooks - MouseProc)?

What I'm trying to achieve is the same result as Spy++, but instead I get coordinates clearly far away from the Spy++ coordinates:

[image]

The "32" app is a DPI-aware 32 bits C# app.

Sources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85)

Comment: If there is no window under the mouse, the `hwnd` can be NULL. You are not checking for that. You are also not checking the return value of `ScreenToClient()` for success/failure.

Comment: Shouldn't `MouseProc` be triggered only when the mouse *is* within a window, therefore `hwnd` would never be null? Anyways, `hwnd` is not null and `ScreenToClient` does return true (and weird coordinates). These are only snippets of what I've tried. What's actually curious is that in my opinion the `pt` should contain values relative to the *window*  instead of the screen since this is a local hook. Something that should be very simple is taking me a lot of time.

Comment: Most hooks are not tied to windows (`WH_CALLWNDPROC/RET` and `WH_CBT` are). A mouse hook is triggered on *any* mouse action within the hooked thread. That is not strictly dependant on a window. What is weird about the coordinates exactly? Please [edit] your question to provide more details. I'm guessing you are likely receiving *virtualized* coordinates if your app is not DPI-aware. There may not be a window under the mouse, so the coordinates can only be relative to the screen.

Comment: @RemyLebeau added images to the post. Hope this helps.

Comment: Spy++ is displaying intercepted `WM_MOUSEMOVE` window messages, it does not use a mouse hook, like you are.  Coordinates in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` are relative to the receiving window's client area. You did not show the output of your hook.

Comment: Does Spy++ install a WH_MESSAGE hook then? Honestly, I still dont get what difference would it make to know the resulting coordinates, whether it is (410, 80) or (392, 92) etc.

Comment: Spy++ uses a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook, yes (in addition to `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET`). See [Spy++ Internals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/spy-internals/) for details.  As for your coordinates, I'm more interested in seeing the *behavioral pattern* of the coordinates rather than the *actual values* themselves.

Comment: Awesome link, Remy. I'll post the coordinates as well as the window positions as soon as I get it to work again, as I'm currently doing many changes.